# Optimization with VBOs

Tags: lwjgl, vbo, vertex-buffer

I am currently working on a cube engine and am experiencing some issues with CPU optimization.

I store all my quad VBO data inside a Block (at x,y,z of a chunk) class, which is stored inside an array with a length of 6 (the maximum number of cube faces). I would prefer to merge it all inside one VBO. The only issue I am having with this is that I cannot find a way to render 6 different textures on each face.

```
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glTranslatef(LENGTH.x * origin.x, LENGTH.y * origin.y, LENGTH.z * origin.z);
    for (int z = 0; z < LENGTH.z; z++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < LENGTH.y; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < LENGTH.x; x++) {
                Block b = get(x, y, z);
                if (b.getBlockType().isTransparent() || b.getVisibleFaces() == 0)
                    continue;
                GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
                GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
                for (int i=0; i < b.getVertexBuffers().length; i++) {
                    QuadVBO q = b.getVertexBuffers()[i];
                    if (q == null || !q.isValid())
                        continue;
                    Game.GRASS.bind(i);
                    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, QuadVBO.faceHandles[i].get(0));
                    GL11.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
                    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, q.getVertexHandle());
                    GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
                    GL11.glNormalPointer(GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, q.getPointerVerticesBytes());
                    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, q.getVerticesCount());
                    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
                }
                GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
                GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            }
        }
    }
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
```

I am aware that this is a horrible way to do it but I cannot seem to find a better way to render these cubes on a screen, any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: What's the actual question here? "What's the right way to do it?" "How can I make this faster?"

Comment: Yeah, I would like to know how I could optimize it/make it faster.

Comment: How to optimize it/make it faster is a very open ended question. It leads to a list of various answers where there isn't one correct answer. It's too broad a question for the site in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pack the textures together into one big texture, use this for the entire VBO.

In your vertices, scale and offset the texture coordinates to "select" which texture to render with, (you'll have to keep track of what texture landed where in the big texture when you make your texture atlas)

Comment: Thanks, I think this is probably the best solution at the moment.